# Connect 2 sources from different processes

Tags: anylogic

I would like to connect 2 sources from different processes. In the second process it should pick my pallets from a pallet rack where I stored them in my first process flow.

**Process 1**: Store the pallets into my pallet racks.

**Process 2:** Pick this number of pallets to a certain time.

Can I connect this processes/ the both source blocks? Its easier for my project to seperat this process. 
I know that it is possible with enter and exit but I would like to know if it is with source too

Answer (score 0):

well... a source generates a completely new agent, and the enter block doesn't, so that's why you should use an enter block instead...

BUT theoretically, you could eventually remove the agent with a sink and create a new one, identical to the previous one with a source... but I don't see why you would do something like that besides a desperate attempt to save memory.... bad practice at its peak.

The real reason why you want to do this, is that you are not aware of the tools that AnyLogic has available to solve whatever you are trying to solve... maybe you are looking for a split block and separate your agent into 2 different processes? Doesn't seem so, since process 1 occurs before process 2, so i dont see why you would even want to separate them

Comment: I still have the problem that I would like to release the pallets to a time from my database which doesn't work. That is the reason. And YES you are right but its normal that I don't know the best solutions while using anylogic for a few weeks.

Comment: well.. then use a wait block between the rack store and rack pick that will free the agents at the time defined by the database... and ask questions based on what you want to achieve... you will get better answers.. or you can use a delay that will have a delay time equal to the time remaining to hit the time on your database...

Comment: do you think I am able to solve my problems like different pallet types or this one when I will study your course (full access version) on your website? :D I am willing to learn more about anylogic and I ask myself if its helpful to improve my knowledge especially functions and the usage of the process modeling library

Comment: i think it will help you for sure

Comment: last question felipe to your course: can I also learn something about IDs? To give materials and objects ids and connect them to a database?